# Table with Exponent

Tags: tables

I have inserted the table below. But a got a lot of errors, saying that is missing $ in the table. Can someone help me ?

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Benchmark} & \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Class S} & \textbf{Class W} & \textbf{Class A} & \textbf{Class B} & \textbf{Class C} & \textbf{Class D} & \textbf{Class E} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{CG} & no. of rows & 1400 & 7000 & 14000 & 75000 & 150000 & 1500000 & 9000000 \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & no. of nonzeros & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 21 & 26 \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & no. of iterations & 15 & 15 & 15 & 75 & 75 & 100 & 100 \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & eigenvalue shift & 10 & 12 & 20 & 60 & 110 & 500 & 1500 \\ \hline
EP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}no. of random-number \\ pairs\end{tabular} &  \[2^2^4\] & \[2^2^5\] & \[2^2^8\] & \[2^3^0\] & \[2^3^2\] & \[2^3^6\] & \[2^4^0\] \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{FT} & grid size & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}64 x 64 \\ x 64\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}128 x 128 \\ x 32\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}256 x 256 \\ x 128\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}512 x 256\\  x 256\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}512 x 512\\  x 512\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}2048 x 1024\\  x 1024\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4096 x 2048\\  x 2048\end{tabular} \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & no. of iterations & 6 & 6 & 6 & 20 & 20 & 25 & 25 \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{IS} & no. of keys & \[2^1^6\] & \[2^2^0\] & \[2^2^3\] & \[2^2^5\] & \[2^2^7\] & \[2^3^1\] &  \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & key max. value & \[2^1^1^\] & \[2^1^6\] & \[2^1^9\] & \[2^2^1\] & \[2^2^3\] & \[2^2^7\] &  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{MG} & grid size & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}32 x 32\\  x 32\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}128 x 128\\  x 128\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}256 x 256\\  x 256\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}256 x 256\\  x 256\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}512 x 512\\  x 512\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1024 x 1024\\  x 1024\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}2048 x 2048\\  x 2048\end{tabular} \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & no. of iterations & 4 & 4 & 4 & 20 & 20 & 50 & 50 \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{BT} & grid size & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}12 x 12\\  x 12\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}24 x 24\\  x 24\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}64 x 64\\  x 64\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}102 x 102\\  x 102\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}162 x 162\\  x 162\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}408 x 408\\  x 408\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1020 x 1020\\  x 1020\end{tabular} \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & no. of iterations & 60 & 200 & 200 & 200 & 200 & 250 & 250 \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & time step & 0.01 & 0.0008 & 0.0008 & 0.0003 & 0.0001 & 0.00002 & 0.000004 \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{(BT-IO)} & write interval & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & Gbytes written & 0.0008 & 0.022 & 0.42 & 1.7 & 6.8 & 135.8 & 2122.4 \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{LU} & grid size & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}12 x 12\\  x 12\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}33 x 33\\  x 33\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}64 x 64\\  x 64\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}102 x 102\\  x 102\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}162 x 162\\  x 162\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}408 x 408\\  x 408\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1020 x 1020\\  x 1020\end{tabular} \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & no. of iterations & 50 & 300 & 250 & 250 & 250 & 300 & 300 \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & time step & 0.5 & 0.0015 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.0 & 0.5 \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{SP} & grid size & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}12 x 12\\  x 12\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}36 x 36\\  x 36\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}64 x 64\\  x 64\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}102 x 102\\  x 102\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}162 x 162\\  x 162\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}408 x 408\\  x 408\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1020 x 1020\\  x 1020\end{tabular} \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & no. of iterations & 100 & 400 & 400 & 400 & 400 & 500 & 500 \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & time step & 0.015 & 0.0015 & 0.0015 & 0.001 & 0.00067 & 0.0003 & 0.0001 \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{UA} & no. of elements & 250 & 700 & 2400 & 8800 & 33500 & 515000 &  \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & no. of mortar points & 11600 & 26700 & 92700 & 334600 & 1262100 & 19500000 &  \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & levels of refinements & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 10 &  \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & no. of iterations & 50 & 100 & 200 & 200 & 200 & 250 &  \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & heat source radius & 0.04 & 0.06 & 0.076 & 0.076 & 0.067 & 0.046 &  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{DC} & input tuples & \[10^3\] & \[10^5\] & \[10^6\] & \[10^7\] &  &  &  \\ \cline{2-9} 
 & no. of dimensions & 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Problem sizes and parameters for each of the classes defined in NPB 3.3.}
\caption*{Source: Adapted from \cite{NPB}}
\label{problem}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Don't use `\[...\]` for mathematics inside the table: this is for "displayed equations" only. Instead, use `$...$` or `\(...\)`, which are for in-line mathematics. (If you really want "display style" mathematics inside the table use `$\displaystyle ...$`.)

Comment: i'm not in a position to test anything, but there are several cells which contain entries like `\[2^1^1^\]`.  i'm not at all sure what you're trying to do there.  the `\[...\]` indicates a display equation, which isn't allowed in a table cell,  also, `^` indicates a superscript; it requires math (hence the `$` error), and you can't have multiple instances of a superscript on the same base; extra levels must be wrapped in braces.  finally, what is `^\]` supposed to mean?  the code `\]` which terminates a display equation can't possibly be a superscript.

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicated the document class you use, the dimensions of the textblock, and the main font and font size. These pieces of information are crucial for judging whether or not a given table will fit on a page in landscape mode.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to fixing the double-exponent issues, you should give serious consideration to making your table more legible and more inviting to your readers' eyes, mainly by giving it a more "open" look. To achieve this objective, consider getting of all vertical lines and most vertical lines, and using the macros of the `booktabs` package to draw the few remaining lines. Also, give your header row a bit more visual structure -- your readers will appreciate it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{7}{c} @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Benchmark} & \textbf{Parameter} & \multicolumn{7}{c@{}}{\textbf{Class}}\\
\cmidrule(l){3-9}
&&\textbf{S} & \textbf{W} & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} \\ 
\midrule
CG & no. of rows & 1400 & 7000 & 14000 & 75000 & 150000 & 1500000 & 9000000 \\  
 & no. of nonzeros & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 21 & 26 \\  
 & no. of iterations & 15 & 15 & 15 & 75 & 75 & 100 & 100 \\  
 & eigenvalue shift & 10 & 12 & 20 & 60 & 110 & 500 & 1500 \\ \addlinespace
EP & no. of random-number pairs &  $2^{2^4}$ & $2^{2^5}$ & $2^{2^8}$ & $2^{3^0}$ & $2^{3^2}$ & $2^{3^6}$ & $2^{4^0}$ \\ \addlinespace
FT & grid size & 
64$\times$64$\times$64 & 128$\times$128$\times$32 & 
256$\times$256$\times$128 & 512$\times$256$\times$256 & 
512$\times$512$\times$512 & 2048$\times$1024$\times$1024 & 
4096$\times$2048$\times$2048 \\  
 & no. of iterations & 6 & 6 & 6 & 20 & 20 & 25 & 25 \\ \addlinespace
IS & no. of keys & $2^{1^6}$ & $2^{2^0}$ & $2^{2^3}$ & $2^{2^5}$ & $2^{2^7}$ & $2^{3^1}$ &  \\  
 & key max. value & $2^{1^1}$ & $2^{1^6}$ & $2^{1^9}$ & $2^{2^1}$ & $2^{2^3}$ & $2^{2^7}$ &  \\ \addlinespace
MG & grid size & 
32$\times$32$\times$32 & 128$\times$128$\times$128 & 
256$\times$256$\times$256 & 256$\times$256$\times$256 & 
512$\times$512$\times$512 & 1024$\times$1024$\times$1024 & 
2048$\times$2048$\times$2048 \\  
 & no. of iterations & 4 & 4 & 4 & 20 & 20 & 50 & 50 \\ \addlinespace
BT & grid size & 
12$\times$12$\times$12 & 24$\times$24$\times$24 & 
64$\times$64$\times$64 & 102$\times$102$\times$102 & 
162$\times$162$\times$162 & 408$\times$408$\times$408 & 
1020$\times$1020$\times$1020 \\  
 & no. of iterations & 60 & 200 & 200 & 200 & 200 & 250 & 250 \\  
 & time step & 0.01 & 0.0008 & 0.0008 & 0.0003 & 0.0001 & 0.00002 & 0.000004 \\ \addlinespace
(BT-IO) & write interval & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\  
 & Gbytes written & 0.0008 & 0.022 & 0.42 & 1.7 & 6.8 & 135.8 & 2122.4 \\ \addlinespace
LU & grid size & 
12$\times$12$\times$12 & 33$\times$33$\times$33 & 64$\times$64$\times$64 & 102$\times$102$\times$102 & 162$\times$162$\times$162 & 408$\times$408$\times$408 & 1020$\times$1020$\times$1020 \\  
 & no. of iterations & 50 & 300 & 250 & 250 & 250 & 300 & 300 \\  
 & time step & 0.5 & 0.0015 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.0 & 0.5 \\ \addlinespace
SP & grid size & 
12$\times$12$\times$12 & 36$\times$36$\times$36 & 64$\times$64$\times$64 & 102$\times$102$\times$102 & 162$\times$162$\times$162 & 408$\times$408$\times$408 & 1020$\times$1020$\times$1020 \\  
 & no. of iterations & 100 & 400 & 400 & 400 & 400 & 500 & 500 \\  
 & time step & 0.015 & 0.0015 & 0.0015 & 0.001 & 0.00067 & 0.0003 & 0.0001 \\ \addlinespace
UA & no. of elements & 250 & 700 & 2400 & 8800 & 33500 & 515000 &  \\  
 & no. of mortar points & 11600 & 26700 & 92700 & 334600 & 1262100 & 19500000 &  \\  
 & levels of refinements & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 10 &  \\  
 & no. of iterations & 50 & 100 & 200 & 200 & 200 & 250 &  \\  
 & heat source radius & 0.04 & 0.06 & 0.076 & 0.076 & 0.067 & 0.046 &  \\ \addlinespace
DC & input tuples & $10^3$ & $10^5$ & $10^6$ & $10^7$ &  &  &  \\  
 & no. of dimensions & 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 &  &  &  \\ 
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Source: Adapted from \cite{NPB}}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Problem sizes and parameters for each of the classes defined in NPB 3.3.}
\label{problem}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really an improvement.

Comment: OP could consider transposing the result to make it easier to compare numbers.  It may also be preferable to split each benchmark into a separate table.  But both of those probably depend on what in the world "Class" means (and "Benchmark").

Comment: @Teepeemm - Thanks. I fully agree with both of your points. As you observe, though, it'll really come down to what "benchmark" and "class" mean...

Answer (score 3):

Errors caused by wrong syntax at writing of exponents -- correct is $a^{b^c}$ -- are explained in above comments. So the main contribution of this answer is off topic: how to improve table layout.

*Edit:* For this the following changes are made:

- for spanning table over available text width in landscape page orientation is used package `tabularx`
- for formatting of big numbers and product are used `siunitx` package. Their option are set locally with `\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,tight-spacing}` where the first one group number even if they have only four digits and second one tied space between digits and math operators.
- for more vertical space around cells contents is added package `cellspace`. Since use of package `siunitx` the `celspace`'s column specifier `S` had to be changed to `C` and for use with `tabularx` column type `X` for preserving features of `X` column type in preamble is added `\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}`.
- for more space for table the size text area is increase, i.e. the borders are reduced to 25 mm with use default vales of package `geometry`.
- instead `landscape` environment I rather use `sidewaystable` from package `rotating` because I'm more familiar with it.

After this changes, which enables that products are now written in one line, table become:

[image]
Complete code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}% <-- added
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added
\usepackage{multirow}% <-- added
\usepackage{cellspace, multirow, tabularx}% 
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}% <-- needs since cellspace otherwise redefine X column type

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[!h]
    \centering
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% X cells are vertical centered
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,tight-spacing}% for formatting \num{...}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \footnotesize
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}% <-- added
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}% <-- added
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|>{\raggedright}C{X}|*{7}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
\hline
\textbf{Benchmark}
    & \textbf{Parameter}
        & \textbf{Class S}  & \textbf{Class W}  & \textbf{Class A}
            & \textbf{Class B}  & \textbf{Class C}  & \textbf{Class D}  & \textbf{Class E} \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{CG}
    & no. of rows
        & \num{1400}        & \num{7000}        & \num{14000}
            & \num{75000}       & \num{150000}      & \num{1500000}     & \num{9000000}     \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & no. of nonzeros
        & 7     & 8     & 11    & 13    & 15    & 21    & 26    \\
\cline{2-9}
    & no. of iterations
        & 15    & 15    & 15    & 75    & 75    & 100   & 100   \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & eigenvalue shift
        & 10    & 12    & 20    & 60    & 110   & 500   & 1500  \\
        \hline
EP  & no. of random-number pairs
        &  2^{2^4}      & 2^{2^5}       & 2^{2^8}       & 2^{3^0}
            & 2^{3^2}       & 2^{3^6}       & 2^{4^0}           \\
            \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{FT}
    & grid size
        & \num{64  x  64 x 64}  & \num{128 x 128 x 32}  & \num{256 x 256 x 128}
            & \num{512 x 256 x 256} & \num{512 x 512 x 512} & \num{2048 x 1024 x 1024}
                & \num{4096 x 2048 x 2048}                      \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & no. of iterations
        & 6     & 6     & 6     & 20    & 20    & 25    & 25    \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{IS}
    & no. of keys
        & 2^{1^6}   & 2^{2^0}   & 2^{2^3}   & 2^{2^5}   & 2^{2^7}   & 2^{3^1}   &  \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & key max. value
        & 2^{1^1}   & 2^{1^6}   & 2^{1^9}   & 2^{2^1}   & 2^{2^3}   & 2^{2^7}   &  \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{MG}
        & grid size & \num{32 x 32 x 32}    & \num{128 x 128 x 128} & \num{256 x 256 x 256}
            & \num{256 x 256 x 256} & \num{512 x 512 x 512} &  \num{1024 x 1024 x 1024}
                & \num{2048 x 2048 x 2048}      \\
    \cline{2-9}
 & no. of iterations
    & 4     & 4     & 4     & 20    & 20    & 50    & 50    \\
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{BT}
    & grid size
        & \num{12 x 12 x 12}    & \num{24 x 24 x 24}    & \num{64 x  64 x 64}
            & \num{102 x 102 x 102} & \num{162 x 162 x 162} & \num{408 x 408 x 408}
                & \num{1020 x 1020  1020}       \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & no. of iterations
        & 60    & 200   & 200   & 200       & 200   & 250   & 250       \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & time step
        & 0.01                  & 0.0008                & 0.0008
            & 0.0003    & 0.0001    & 0.00002               & 0.000004 \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{(BT-IO)}
    & write interval
        & 5         & 5         & 5         & 5     & 5     & 5         & 5     \\
    \cline{2-9}
 & Gbytes written
    & 0.0008        & 0.022     & 0.42      & 1.7   & 6.8   & 135.8     & 2122.4 \\
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{LU}
    & grid size
        & \num{12 x 12 x 12}    & \num{33 x 33 x 33}    & \num{64 x  64 x 64}
            & \num{102 x 102 x 102} & \num{162 x 162 x 162} & \num{408 x 408 x 408}
                & \num{1020 x 1020 x 1020}  \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & no. of iterations
        & 50        & 300       & 250       & 250   & 250   & 300       & 300   \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & time step
        & 0.5       & 0.0015    & 2.0       & 2.0   & 2.0   & 1.0       & 0.5   \\
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{SP}
    & grid size
        & \num{12 x 12 x 12}    & \num{36 x 36 x 36}    & \num{64 x  64 x 64}
            & \num{102 x 102 x 102} & \num{162 x 162 x 162} & \num{408 x 408 x 408}
                & \num{1020 x 1020 x 1020}                                  \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & no. of iterations
        & 100       & 400       & 400       & 400   & 400   & 500       & 500   \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & time step
        & 0.015     & 0.0015    & 0.0015    & 0.001 & 0.00067
            & 0.0003    & 0.0001 \\
    \hline
\multirow{8}{*}{UA}
    & no. of elements
        & 250       & 700       & \num{2400}    & \num{8800}
            & \num{33500}   & \num{515000}      &       \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & no. of mortar points
        & \num{11600}   & \num{26700}       & \num{92700}   & \num{334600}
            & \num{1262100} & \num{19500000}    &       \\
    \cline{2-9}
 & levels of refinements
    & 4     & 5     & 6     & 7     & 8     & 10    &  \\
    \cline{2-9}
 & no. of iterations
    & 50    & 100   & 200   & 200   & 200   & 250   &  \\
    \cline{2-9}
 & heat source radius
    & 0.04  & 0.06  & 0.076 & 0.076 & 0.067 & 0.046 &  \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{DC}
    & input tuples
        & 10^3      & 10^5  & 10^6  & 10^7 &    &   &  \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & no. of dimensions
        & 5         & 10    & 15    & 20    &   &   &  \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{9}{Cl}{Source: Adapted from \cite{NPB}}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Problem sizes and parameters for each of the classes defined in NPB 3.3.}
\label{problem}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

*Edit (2):* if you increase text area with selecting margins to be 25 mm and move `\cpation*{...}` to table, than you can increase used font size to `\small, similarly as in Mico answer, even in this table design.

Comment: We almost had the same ideas on this case!

Comment: :-), but in some details are (small) differences. by the way, I try to employ `siunitx` for better formatting big numbers, but then discover that seems it is not compatible with `cellspace`...

Comment: A minor nit to pick: the location specifier `[!h]` is meaningless when associated with a `sidewaystable` -- delete it.

Comment: @Zarko: It is compatible, but the  pre-specifier `S` must be replaced with `C`, as siunitx uses `S`  (so it is definitely incompatible with `siunitx+tabulary`. B.t.w. I'm not sure if it works with the S column type (in the sense of siunitx), and if it is, whether one has to code `CS` or `C{S}`.

Comment: @Bernard, thanks to your comment I succeed to manage use of the `siunitx`. Now, to my opinion, the table has better appearance.

Comment: @Zarko: it indeed looks nicer than mine. I just wondered whether it isn't a little too wide? I dared not write the grid sizes on a single line, and used `\makecell` instead. I must say I didn't think of the `tight-spacing` option of siunitx.

Comment: @Bernard, it seems that both of us bit Mico with his answer :-). Anyway, with your help I now know how to use `cellspace` package in presence of the `siunitx` as well of the `tabularx` package. Thank you very much for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution. You had double exponentials  not correctly coded: you can't write `a^b^c`  (an ambiguous notation anyway) but have to use a pair of braces: `a^{b^c}`.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array, multirow, makecell, cellspace, caption}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{1pt}
    \usepackage{lscape}

    \begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}%[!htb]
\footnotesize\renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.7}}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|*{7}{>{$}Sc<{$}|}}
\\[-1cm]
\hline
\textbf{Benchmark} & \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Class S} & \textbf{Class W} & \textbf{Class A} & \textbf{Class B} & \textbf{Class C} & \textbf{Class D} & \textbf{Class E} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{CG} & no. of rows & 1400 & 7000 & 14000 & 75000 & 150000 & 1500000 & 9000000 \\ \cline{2-9}
 & no. of nonzeros & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 21 & 26 \\ \cline{2-9}
 & no. of iterations & 15 & 15 & 15 & 75 & 75 & 100 & 100 \\ \cline{2-9}
 & eigenvalue shift & 10 & 12 & 20 & 60 & 110 & 500 & 1500 \\ \hline
EP & \makecell{no. of random-number \\ pair} & 2^{2^4} & 2^{2^5} & 2^{2^8} & 2^{3^0} & 2^{3^2} & 2^{3^6} & 2^{4^0} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{FT} & grid size & \makecell{64 \times 64 \\ \times 64} & \makecell{128 \times 128 \\ \times 32} & \makecell{256 \times 256 \\ \times 128} & \makecell{512 \times 256\\ \times 256} & \makecell{512 \times 512\\ \times 512} & \makecell{2048 \times 1024\\ \times 1024} & \makecell{4096 \times 2048\\ \times 2048} \\ \cline{2-9}
 & no. of iterations & 6 & 6 & 6 & 20 & 20 & 25 & 25 \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{IS} & no. of keys & 2^{1^6} & 2^{2^0} & 2^{2^3} & 2^{2^5} & 2^{2^7} & 2^{3^1} & \\ \cline{2-9}
 & key max. value & 2^{1^1} & 2^{1^6} & 2^{1^9} & 2^{2^1} & 2^{2^3} & 2^{2^7} & \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{MG} & grid size & \makecell{32 \times 32\\ \times 32} & \makecell{128 \times 128\\ \times 128} & \makecell{256 \times 256\\ \times 256} & \makecell{256 \times 256\\ \times 256} & \makecell{512 \times 512\\ \times 512} & \makecell{1024 \times 1024\\ \times 1024} & \makecell{2048 \times 2048\\ \times 2048} \\ \cline{2-9}
 & no. of iterations & 4 & 4 & 4 & 20 & 20 & 50 & 50 \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{BT} & grid size & \makecell{12 \times 12\\ \times 12} & \makecell{24 \times 24\\ \times 24} & \makecell{64 \times 64\\ \times 64} & \makecell{102 \times 102\\ \times 102} & \makecell{162 \times 162\\ \times 162} & \makecell{408 \times 408\\ \times 408} & \makecell{1020 \times 1020\\ \times 1020} \\ \cline{2-9}
 & no. of iterations & 60 & 200 & 200 & 200 & 200 & 250 & 250 \\ \cline{2-9}
 & time step & 0.01 & 0.0008 & 0.0008 & 0.0003 & 0.0001 & 0.00002 & 0.000004 \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{(BT-IO)} & write interval & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\ \cline{2-9}
 & Gbytes written & 0.0008 & 0.022 & 0.42 & 1.7 & 6.8 & 135.8 & 2122.4 \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{LU} & grid size & \makecell{12 \times 12\\ \times 12} & \makecell{33 \times 33\\ \times 33} & \makecell{64 \times 64\\ \times 64} & \makecell{102 \times 102\\ \times 102} & \makecell{162 \times 162\\ \times 162} & \makecell{408 \times 408\\ \times 408} & \makecell{1020 \times 1020\\ \times 1020} \\ \cline{2-9}
 & no. of iterations & 50 & 300 & 250 & 250 & 250 & 300 & 300 \\ \cline{2-9}
 & time step & 0.5 & 0.0015 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 & 1.0 & 0.5 \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{SP} & grid size & \makecell{12 \times 12\\ \times 12} & \makecell{36 \times 36\\ \times 36} & \makecell{64 \times 64\\ \times 64} & \makecell{102 \times 102\\ \times 102} & \makecell{162 \times 162\\ \times 162} & \makecell{408 \times 408\\ \times 408} & \makecell{1020 \times 1020\\ \times 1020} \\ \cline{2-9}
 & no. of iterations & 100 & 400 & 400 & 400 & 400 & 500 & 500 \\ \cline{2-9}
 & time step & 0.015 & 0.0015 & 0.0015 & 0.001 & 0.00067 & 0.0003 & 0.0001 \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{UA} & no. of elements & 250 & 700 & 2400 & 8800 & 33500 & 515000 & \\ \cline{2-9}
 & no. of mortar points & 11600 & 26700 & 92700 & 334600 & 1262100 & 19500000 & \\ \cline{2-9}
 & levels of refinements & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 10 & \\ \cline{2-9}
 & no. of iterations & 50 & 100 & 200 & 200 & 200 & 250 & \\ \cline{2-9}
 & heat source radius & 0.04 & 0.06 & 0.076 & 0.076 & 0.067 & 0.046 & \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{DC} & input tuples & 10^3 & 10^5 & 10^6 & 10^7 & & & \\ \cline{2-9}
 & no. of dimensions & 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & & & \\ \hline
 \noalign{\medskip}
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{Source: Adapted from \cite{NPB}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Problem sizes and parameters for each of the classes defined in NPB 3.3.}
\label{problem}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

    \end{document}
```

[image]